SQL Get all records which have at least 5 associations which meet conditions
I'm a bit lost with a query I am trying to write. As the question states, I am attempting to return all records from a table which have at least 5 associated records which meed a certain criteria. Specifically, I have Cars and Drivers. A Driver can have many Cars and I would like to return all drivers which have at least 5 cars which were created after 3 weeks ago.
the query below gives me the ids of the drivers which have at least one car created in the last 3 weeks, but I cant work out how to add an additional count step so that I return only the ids of the drivers which have at least 5!
SELECT DISTINCT d.id FROM drivers d
     JOIN cars c ON c.driver_id = d.id
     WHERE c.created_at >= NOW() - '3 weeks'::INTERVAL

I was hoping I would be able to to do something like (pseudo code obviously)
SELECT DISTINCT d.id FROM drivers d
     JOIN cars c ON c.driver_id = d.id
     WHERE c.created_at >= NOW() - '3 weeks'::INTERVAL
     AND d.id IN (SELECT <driver ids which have more than 5 cars created in the last 3 weeks>)

but it's not proving to be this simple.
I'm working in Rails but have ended up writing the raw query. Any advice?

Since you are using Postgres you can use GROUP BY and HAVING like so:
Driver
  .joins(:cars)
  .where(cars: {created_at: 3.weeks.ago..})
  .group(:id)
  .having(Arel.star.count.gt(4))

This will produce the following SQL
SELECT 
  drivers.*
FROM 
  drivers
  INNER JOIN cars ON cars.driver_id = drivers.id 
WHERE 
  cars.created_at >= [3 weeks ago date] 
GROUP BY 
  drivers.id 
HAVING 
  COUNT(*) > 4 

In keeping with your current implementation, or for databases that do not support grouping solely by the primary key, we can go with
Driver.where(id: 
  Car.select(:driver_id)
    .where(created_at: 3.weeks.ago..)
    .group(:driver_id)
    .having(Arel.star.count.gt(4))
)

Which will produce
SELECT 
  drivers.*
FROM 
  drivers
WHERE 
  drivers.id IN ( 
    SELECT 
      cars.driver_id
    FROM
      cars
    WHERE 
     cars.created_at >= [3 weeks ago date] 
    GROUP BY 
      cars.driver_id
    HAVING 
      COUNT(*) > 4 
)

